# how to create user defined id in mongodb rather then _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a schema to add the book details i wanted to maintain a user defined id called book_id rather than mongodb _id ,

To do that i was making a service call to find the total number documents in the collection and was increment the response by 1 and then  assign to book_id

Is there a way to do it only in the server side like we use auto-increment in MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define your own _id pattern. also you can add incremental values to _id field of a mongodb collection. but you can't use any field instead of _id. because mongodb cares _id for preventing duplication. mongodb's approach is different any rdbms. but if you want to use book_id, you can use as a field. but a mongodb collection always have _id field.

for your answer, you can read [this](https://blog.serverdensity.com/switching-to-mongodb-and-auto-increment/) document.

also in [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/) you can find official mongodb sequence/auto-increment information.

you can apply this code on mongo shell.

```
db.book_counters.insert(
{
  book_id: "bookid",
  seq: 0
}
) 

function getNextSequence(book) {
 var ret = db.book_counters.findAndModify(
      {
        query: { book_id: book },
        update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
        new: true
      }
 );

return ret.seq;
}

db.book.insert(
{
 book_id: getNextSequence("bookid"),
 book: "Harry Potter"
}
)

db.book.insert(
 {
 book_id: getNextSequence("bookid"),
 book: "LOTR"
}
)
```

Comment: thank you i just wanted to add book_id has the field router.route('/book')
  .post(function(req,res){
      var book = new book();
      book.book_id=1;
      book = req.body;
      book.save(function(err,result){
        if(err){
          res.status(500).send(err.message);
          console.log(err.stack);
        }else{
          res.send(result);
        }
      })
    }
  }); for this use case how to generate the bookid

Comment: you can use book_id but _id must be.

Comment: yes i want both of them where book_id is total number of books +1 every time we add a book

Comment: can u please add that to the  /book code present in previous comment

Comment: i added code to answer. you can do this operation on mongo shell. after this operation, your insert operations take care sequence/auto-increment.